# pandas dataframe sum of shift(x) for x in range(1, n)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with like this, and want to add a new column that is the equivalent of applying `shift` n times. For example, let n = 2:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(numpy.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 2)), columns=['a','b'])

   a  b
0  0  3
1  7  0
2  6  6
3  6  0
4  5  0
5  0  7
6  8  0
7  8  7
8  4  4
9  2  2

df['c'] = df['b'].shift(1) + df['b'].shift(2)

   a  b     c
0  0  3   NaN
1  7  0   NaN
2  6  6   3.0
3  6  0   6.0
4  5  0   6.0
5  0  7   0.0
6  8  0   7.0
7  8  7   7.0
8  4  4   7.0
9  2  2  11.0
```

In this manner, column `c` gets the sum of the previous `n` values from column `b`.

Other than a loop, is there a better way to accomplish this for a large `n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `rolling()` method with a `window` of `2`:

```
df['c'] = df.b.rolling(window = 2).sum().shift()

df
    a   b     c
0   0   3   NaN
1   7   0   NaN
2   6   6   3.0
3   6   0   6.0
4   5   0   6.0
5   0   7   0.0
6   8   0   7.0
7   8   7   7.0
8   4   4   7.0
9   2   2   11.0
```