# Use Trailing X Range of Rows when Defining a New Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking to turn a `for` loop, when creating values for a new column, into a one line statement using `numpy.where()` instead. I'm trying to implement the Doji logic [here](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/thinkScript/Functions/Tech-Analysis/IsDoji) in Python, but that's not really important to the question I have. Before this gets downvoted, I'm providing this big dataset to ensure that whoever helps me with this is working with the same dataset that I am, and to ensure that there are a few instances of `True` to compare to.

To reproduce, (warning, long df creation ahead) create this dataframe of data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a reproducible, static dataframe.
# 1 minute SPY data. Skip to the bottom...
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:30",
        "open": "457.2",
        "high": "457.29",
        "low": "456.78",
        "close": "456.9383",
        "volume": "594142"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:31",
        "open": "456.94",
        "high": "457.07",
        "low": "456.8",
        "close": "456.995",
        "volume": "194061"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:32",
        "open": "456.99",
        "high": "457.22",
        "low": "456.84",
        "close": "457.21",
        "volume": "186114"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:33",
        "open": "457.22",
        "high": "457.45",
        "low": "457.2011",
        "close": "457.308",
        "volume": "294158"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:34",
        "open": "457.31",
        "high": "457.4",
        "low": "457.25",
        "close": "457.32",
        "volume": "172574"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:35",
        "open": "457.31",
        "high": "457.48",
        "low": "457.18",
        "close": "457.44",
        "volume": "396668"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:36",
        "open": "457.48",
        "high": "457.6511",
        "low": "457.44",
        "close": "457.57",
        "volume": "186777"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:37",
        "open": "457.5699",
        "high": "457.73",
        "low": "457.5699",
        "close": "457.69",
        "volume": "187596"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:38",
        "open": "457.7",
        "high": "457.73",
        "low": "457.54",
        "close": "457.63",
        "volume": "185570"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:39",
        "open": "457.63",
        "high": "457.64",
        "low": "457.31",
        "close": "457.59",
        "volume": "164707"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:40",
        "open": "457.59",
        "high": "457.72",
        "low": "457.46",
        "close": "457.7199",
        "volume": "167438"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:41",
        "open": "457.72",
        "high": "457.8",
        "low": "457.68",
        "close": "457.72",
        "volume": "199951"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:42",
        "open": "457.73",
        "high": "457.74",
        "low": "457.6",
        "close": "457.62",
        "volume": "152134"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:43",
        "open": "457.6",
        "high": "457.65",
        "low": "457.45",
        "close": "457.5077",
        "volume": "142530"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:44",
        "open": "457.51",
        "high": "457.64",
        "low": "457.4001",
        "close": "457.61",
        "volume": "122575"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:45",
        "open": "457.61",
        "high": "457.76",
        "low": "457.58",
        "close": "457.75",
        "volume": "119886"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:46",
        "open": "457.74",
        "high": "457.75",
        "low": "457.37",
        "close": "457.38",
        "volume": "183157"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:47",
        "open": "457.42",
        "high": "457.49",
        "low": "457.37",
        "close": "457.44",
        "volume": "128542"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:48",
        "open": "457.43",
        "high": "457.49",
        "low": "457.33",
        "close": "457.44",
        "volume": "154181"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:49",
        "open": "457.43",
        "high": "457.5898",
        "low": "457.42",
        "close": "457.47",
        "volume": "163063"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:50",
        "open": "457.45",
        "high": "457.59",
        "low": "457.44",
        "close": "457.555",
        "volume": "96229"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:51",
        "open": "457.56",
        "high": "457.61",
        "low": "457.31",
        "close": "457.4217",
        "volume": "110380"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:52",
        "open": "457.42",
        "high": "457.56",
        "low": "457.42",
        "close": "457.47",
        "volume": "107518"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:53",
        "open": "457.475",
        "high": "457.51",
        "low": "457.4",
        "close": "457.48",
        "volume": "78062"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:54",
        "open": "457.49",
        "high": "457.57",
        "low": "457.42",
        "close": "457.46",
        "volume": "133883"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:55",
        "open": "457.47",
        "high": "457.56",
        "low": "457.45",
        "close": "457.51",
        "volume": "98998"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:56",
        "open": "457.51",
        "high": "457.54",
        "low": "457.43",
        "close": "457.43",
        "volume": "110237"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:57",
        "open": "457.43",
        "high": "457.65",
        "low": "457.375",
        "close": "457.65",
        "volume": "98794"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:58",
        "open": "457.66",
        "high": "457.69",
        "low": "457.35",
        "close": "457.45",
        "volume": "262154"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:59",
        "open": "457.45",
        "high": "457.47",
        "low": "457.33",
        "close": "457.4",
        "volume": "74685"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:00",
        "open": "457.41",
        "high": "457.48",
        "low": "457.18",
        "close": "457.38",
        "volume": "166617"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:01",
        "open": "457.39",
        "high": "457.7",
        "low": "457.39",
        "close": "457.5",
        "volume": "265649"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:02",
        "open": "457.51",
        "high": "457.57",
        "low": "457.39",
        "close": "457.53",
        "volume": "131947"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:03",
        "open": "457.53",
        "high": "457.54",
        "low": "457.4",
        "close": "457.51",
        "volume": "80111"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:04",
        "open": "457.51",
        "high": "457.62",
        "low": "457.5",
        "close": "457.6101",
        "volume": "117174"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:05",
        "open": "457.621",
        "high": "457.64",
        "low": "457.51",
        "close": "457.58",
        "volume": "168758"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:06",
        "open": "457.58",
        "high": "457.64",
        "low": "457.46",
        "close": "457.61",
        "volume": "84076"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:07",
        "open": "457.62",
        "high": "457.7401",
        "low": "457.62",
        "close": "457.66",
        "volume": "125156"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:08",
        "open": "457.665",
        "high": "457.69",
        "low": "457.5",
        "close": "457.67",
        "volume": "116919"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:09",
        "open": "457.69",
        "high": "457.72",
        "low": "457.5",
        "close": "457.57",
        "volume": "102551"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:10",
        "open": "457.56",
        "high": "457.75",
        "low": "457.56",
        "close": "457.7",
        "volume": "109165"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:11",
        "open": "457.7",
        "high": "457.725",
        "low": "457.63",
        "close": "457.66",
        "volume": "146209"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:12",
        "open": "457.665",
        "high": "457.88",
        "low": "457.64",
        "close": "457.86",
        "volume": "210620"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:13",
        "open": "457.855",
        "high": "457.96",
        "low": "457.83",
        "close": "457.95",
        "volume": "159975"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:14",
        "open": "457.95",
        "high": "458.02",
        "low": "457.93",
        "close": "457.95",
        "volume": "152042"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:15",
        "open": "457.96",
        "high": "458.15",
        "low": "457.96",
        "close": "458.08",
        "volume": "146047"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:16",
        "open": "458.085",
        "high": "458.17",
        "low": "457.99",
        "close": "458.15",
        "volume": "100732"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:17",
        "open": "458.17",
        "high": "458.33",
        "low": "458.155",
        "close": "458.245",
        "volume": "235072"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:18",
        "open": "458.25",
        "high": "458.29",
        "low": "458.14",
        "close": "458.16",
        "volume": "422002"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:19",
        "open": "458.17",
        "high": "458.2801",
        "low": "458.1699",
        "close": "458.28",
        "volume": "114611"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:20",
        "open": "458.29",
        "high": "458.39",
        "low": "458.24",
        "close": "458.37",
        "volume": "241797"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:21",
        "open": "458.37",
        "high": "458.42",
        "low": "458.31",
        "close": "458.345",
        "volume": "124824"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:22",
        "open": "458.33",
        "high": "458.49",
        "low": "458.33",
        "close": "458.47",
        "volume": "132125"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:23",
        "open": "458.47",
        "high": "458.48",
        "low": "458.38",
        "close": "458.42",
        "volume": "204075"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:24",
        "open": "458.42",
        "high": "458.44",
        "low": "458.29",
        "close": "458.34",
        "volume": "126912"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:25",
        "open": "458.33",
        "high": "458.34",
        "low": "458.18",
        "close": "458.1899",
        "volume": "101231"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:26",
        "open": "458.17",
        "high": "458.24",
        "low": "458.13",
        "close": "458.2",
        "volume": "72580"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:27",
        "open": "458.2",
        "high": "458.21",
        "low": "458.14",
        "close": "458.19",
        "volume": "68729"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:28",
        "open": "458.185",
        "high": "458.23",
        "low": "458.13",
        "close": "458.1912",
        "volume": "54422"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:29",
        "open": "458.2",
        "high": "458.34",
        "low": "458.2",
        "close": "458.21",
        "volume": "138841"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:30",
        "open": "458.2",
        "high": "458.25",
        "low": "458.11",
        "close": "458.1119",
        "volume": "92084"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:31",
        "open": "458.12",
        "high": "458.205",
        "low": "458.04",
        "close": "458.16",
        "volume": "146496"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:32",
        "open": "458.1477",
        "high": "458.27",
        "low": "458.1477",
        "close": "458.205",
        "volume": "94342"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:33",
        "open": "458.205",
        "high": "458.25",
        "low": "458.17",
        "close": "458.195",
        "volume": "94324"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:34",
        "open": "458.2",
        "high": "458.29",
        "low": "458.1975",
        "close": "458.23",
        "volume": "96848"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:35",
        "open": "458.23",
        "high": "458.24",
        "low": "458.175",
        "close": "458.2",
        "volume": "83119"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:36",
        "open": "458.19",
        "high": "458.23",
        "low": "458.08",
        "close": "458.12",
        "volume": "99426"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:37",
        "open": "458.13",
        "high": "458.18",
        "low": "458.08",
        "close": "458.17",
        "volume": "65034"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:38",
        "open": "458.17",
        "high": "458.26",
        "low": "458.14",
        "close": "458.245",
        "volume": "149649"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:39",
        "open": "458.24",
        "high": "458.359",
        "low": "458.24",
        "close": "458.25",
        "volume": "120754"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:40",
        "open": "458.26",
        "high": "458.31",
        "low": "458.22",
        "close": "458.25",
        "volume": "91216"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:41",
        "open": "458.25",
        "high": "458.25",
        "low": "458.1216",
        "close": "458.15",
        "volume": "51800"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:42",
        "open": "458.15",
        "high": "458.2",
        "low": "457.96",
        "close": "458.03",
        "volume": "101539"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:43",
        "open": "458.02",
        "high": "458.02",
        "low": "457.94",
        "close": "458",
        "volume": "86088"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:44",
        "open": "457.9903",
        "high": "458.04",
        "low": "457.84",
        "close": "457.89",
        "volume": "95357"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:45",
        "open": "457.9",
        "high": "457.955",
        "low": "457.81",
        "close": "457.83",
        "volume": "93449"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:46",
        "open": "457.83",
        "high": "458.01",
        "low": "457.822",
        "close": "457.965",
        "volume": "100225"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:47",
        "open": "457.9789",
        "high": "458.08",
        "low": "457.9499",
        "close": "458.07",
        "volume": "277336"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:48",
        "open": "458.05",
        "high": "458.2",
        "low": "458.05",
        "close": "458.1999",
        "volume": "144024"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:49",
        "open": "458.191",
        "high": "458.25",
        "low": "458.14",
        "close": "458.16",
        "volume": "89625"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:50",
        "open": "458.1566",
        "high": "458.3",
        "low": "458.12",
        "close": "458.28",
        "volume": "99426"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:51",
        "open": "458.279",
        "high": "458.34",
        "low": "458.23",
        "close": "458.32",
        "volume": "136285"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:52",
        "open": "458.32",
        "high": "458.35",
        "low": "458.26",
        "close": "458.345",
        "volume": "59124"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:53",
        "open": "458.35",
        "high": "458.4",
        "low": "458.34",
        "close": "458.35",
        "volume": "68658"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:54",
        "open": "458.34",
        "high": "458.37",
        "low": "458.31",
        "close": "458.33",
        "volume": "71029"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:55",
        "open": "458.32",
        "high": "458.36",
        "low": "458.28",
        "close": "458.3",
        "volume": "92136"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:56",
        "open": "458.31",
        "high": "458.38",
        "low": "458.27",
        "close": "458.3475",
        "volume": "62093"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:57",
        "open": "458.34",
        "high": "458.355",
        "low": "458.3",
        "close": "458.35",
        "volume": "61162"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:58",
        "open": "458.35",
        "high": "458.36",
        "low": "458.32",
        "close": "458.325",
        "volume": "66327"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:59",
        "open": "458.33",
        "high": "458.34",
        "low": "458.09",
        "close": "458.125",
        "volume": "133687"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:00",
        "open": "458.12",
        "high": "458.31",
        "low": "458.12",
        "close": "458.145",
        "volume": "96792"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:01",
        "open": "458.16",
        "high": "458.29",
        "low": "458.11",
        "close": "458.19",
        "volume": "70797"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:02",
        "open": "458.2",
        "high": "458.25",
        "low": "458.14",
        "close": "458.23",
        "volume": "83904"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:03",
        "open": "458.25",
        "high": "458.26",
        "low": "458.16",
        "close": "458.18",
        "volume": "59358"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:04",
        "open": "458.185",
        "high": "458.19",
        "low": "457.96",
        "close": "457.975",
        "volume": "115402"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:05",
        "open": "457.98",
        "high": "458.14",
        "low": "457.98",
        "close": "458.14",
        "volume": "134739"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:06",
        "open": "458.13",
        "high": "458.1401",
        "low": "457.99",
        "close": "458.03",
        "volume": "132432"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:07",
        "open": "458.03",
        "high": "458.11",
        "low": "457.97",
        "close": "457.97",
        "volume": "332595"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:08",
        "open": "457.96",
        "high": "458.01",
        "low": "457.89",
        "close": "457.99",
        "volume": "112124"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:09",
        "open": "458",
        "high": "458.02",
        "low": "457.92",
        "close": "458.01",
        "volume": "49906"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:10",
        "open": "458.01",
        "high": "458.13",
        "low": "458.01",
        "close": "458.13",
        "volume": "378085"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:11",
        "open": "458.13",
        "high": "458.13",
        "low": "458.03",
        "close": "458.11",
        "volume": "47473"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:12",
        "open": "458.11",
        "high": "458.13",
        "low": "458.04",
        "close": "458.0699",
        "volume": "307628"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:13",
        "open": "458.07",
        "high": "458.16",
        "low": "458.04",
        "close": "458.13",
        "volume": "39463"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:14",
        "open": "458.119",
        "high": "458.119",
        "low": "458.02",
        "close": "458.06",
        "volume": "37030"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:15",
        "open": "458.06",
        "high": "458.18",
        "low": "458.05",
        "close": "458.18",
        "volume": "67514"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:16",
        "open": "458.175",
        "high": "458.21",
        "low": "458.1",
        "close": "458.185",
        "volume": "87491"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:17",
        "open": "458.18",
        "high": "458.195",
        "low": "458.14",
        "close": "458.17",
        "volume": "37629"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:18",
        "open": "458.18",
        "high": "458.27",
        "low": "458.159",
        "close": "458.26",
        "volume": "72492"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:19",
        "open": "458.25",
        "high": "458.25",
        "low": "458.15",
        "close": "458.19",
        "volume": "42138"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:20",
        "open": "458.2",
        "high": "458.31",
        "low": "458.2",
        "close": "458.25",
        "volume": "66885"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:21",
        "open": "458.24",
        "high": "458.27",
        "low": "458.21",
        "close": "458.23",
        "volume": "48999"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:22",
        "open": "458.23",
        "high": "458.3",
        "low": "458.195",
        "close": "458.29",
        "volume": "49565"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:23",
        "open": "458.3",
        "high": "458.31",
        "low": "458.24",
        "close": "458.31",
        "volume": "51411"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:24",
        "open": "458.31",
        "high": "458.31",
        "low": "458.18",
        "close": "458.23",
        "volume": "43851"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 11:25",
        "open": "458.24",
        "high": "458.27",
        "low": "458.2",
        "close": "458.25",
        "volume": "35606"
    }
])
```

... then see the rest of the code below. Just copy and paste the code above the code below.

```
# Convert open and close to numeric re: the .csv to .json
# converter tool I used online...
df['open'] = pd.to_numeric(df['open'])
df['close'] = pd.to_numeric(df['close'])

# Define the Doji lookback length and body factor
length = 20
bodyFactor = 0.05

# First, create a column that defines each row's
# "body height"
df['bodyHeight'] = abs(df['close'] - df['open'])

# Create a placeholder column for "isDoji" flag
df['isDoji'] = False

# WORKING EXAMPLE
# Iterate through the df
for i in range(length, len(df)):

    # If the current body height <= the rolling average of prev
    # body heights * bodyFactor, set it to true
    if abs(df['close'].iloc[i] - df['open'].iloc[i]) <= df['bodyHeight'].iloc[i-length:i].mean() * bodyFactor:
        df['isDoji'].iloc[i] = True

# Export the correct answer dataset to compare the next function
# to below
df.to_csv("correct_answers.csv", index=False)

# NON-WORKING EXAMPLE
# What I'd like to do is NOT use a for loop to do the above. I envision
# we can use np.where() here? But I don't know how to designate a range
# of rows without using iloc. I know you can use .shift() here, but 
# if the length is 20, or more, I don't want to manually add 20 .shifts(x)
# to the code. Pseudocode would look like this
df['isDoji2'] = np.where(abs(df['close'].iloc[i] - df['open'].iloc[i]) <= df['bodyHeight'].iloc[i-length:i].mean() * bodyFactor , True, False)
# ... but obviously the iloc[i]'s don't work here.

# Check if isDoji2 matches isDoji
df.to_csv("correct_answers2.csv", index=False)
```

I'm hoping you can see what I'm trying to accomplish here, and I don't know 100% if this can be done WITHOUT using a for loop, but figured I would check because the less iteration I have to do with the dataset I'm working on, the better off I'll be.

Can you do this kind of column calculation using the previous X rows in one line like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy smokes I got it! Thanks to inspo from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40700762/pandas-dataframe-sum-of-shiftx-for-x-in-range1-n).

This does what I'm looking for, verified by the final dataset that I save:

```
df['isDoji2'] = np.where(abs(df['close'] - df['open']) <= (abs(df['close'] - df['open'])).rolling(window = length).mean().shift() * bodyFactor , True, False)
```

So I can just take the rolling mean of the abs(close - open) and do a shift afterwards. Thanks for letting me hash that out! haha